# Query getting executed in MySQL but while debugging gets error in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have one insert query in which I am trying to copy table1 data to table2. Now Query works fine when I directly execute in MySQL but when I tried to debug via VB.Net"

```
INSERT INTO newMedicinesOrders (`OrderID`,`medicineName`, `power`, `form`, `fQuantity`, `iQuantity`, `type`, `cost`, `prescriptionLink`, `userID`) SELECT `orderID`, `name`, `power`, `form`, `fQuantity`, `iQuantity`, `type`, `mrp`, `prescriptionLink`, `userID` from myCart WHERE userID = '1'
```

I get an error message that says

> Unknown column 'orderID' in 'field list'

vb code

```
Try
            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO newMedicinesOrders (`OrderID`,`medicineName`, `power`, `form`, `fQuantity`, `iQuantity`, `type`, `cost`, `prescriptionLink`, `userID`) SELECT `orderID`, `name`, `power`, `form`, `fQuantity`, `iQuantity`, `type`, `mrp`, `prescriptionLink`, `userID` from myCart WHERE userID = '" + userid.Text + "'"

            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Success.');</script>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
```

Comment: @eggyal it shows exption message as "Unknown column 'orderID' in 'field list' "

Comment: Can we see the code that invokes this query in vb.net?

Comment: @eggyal Is it ok if I show you debugging mode screenshot?

Comment: It's better to copy/paste the code into your question—but if there's information that can only be communicated in a screenshot then sure, do that.

Comment: @eggyal I have posted vb code in my post

Comment: not sure if this will make a difference however could you hard code the value 1 into the .net to see if it would work since that is the only difference?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error comes from the fact that you are using `SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()`

From [this description](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-executereader-executenonquery.htm) :

> **ExecuteReader** used for getting the query results as a DataReader object. It is readonly forward only retrieval of records and it uses select command to read through the table from the first to the last.
>
> **ExecuteNonQuery** used for executing queries that does not return any data. It is used to execute the sql statements like update, insert, delete etc. ExecuteNonQuery executes the command and returns the number of rows affected.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this is how you execute an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement :

```
Public Sub CreateCommand(ByVal queryString As String, ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

However, I did not find information on what happens when you execute an `INSERT` command using `ExecuteReader()`, but I guess that's what happens...